# How to count the ion-select Childs (ion-option)?

Tags: angular, ionic2

It possible to count the ion-option inside the ion-select?

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-option></ion-option>
  <ion-option></ion-option>
  <ion-option></ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

`console.log(something)` and I will got 3 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to count them ? I am asking this maybe to find a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]
Sorry for my last answer which was wrong.

You can also use [Viewchild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to access to the dom element if you don't want to use document.getElementById('mySelect')

So the solution with ViewChild

myPage.html

```
 <ion-select #mySelect>
     <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

First use it in your components:

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Then Declare your variable:

```
@ViewChild('mySelect') selectDom;

 ionViewDidLoad(){
      console.log(this.selectDom._options.length); // = 6 in my case
  }
```

Comment: Not worked , can u get an example about the VIewChild

Comment: I will try to make a sample give me a minute

Comment: Do you look the length after the display of all values? (after that ngFor got executed)

Comment: I think the ngFor is worked, but in my case doest work because I'm using the async pipe,, On load the viewChild count the child and returning zero. do u have a solution for that

Comment: I need the count the ion-select Childs after the array subscription

Comment: Yes don't forgot that obervable is asynchronous so you have to refresh the number of option in the callback.

Comment: how to refresh the number of the ion-options in the call back

Comment: Just use the this.myvar= this.selectDom._options.length in your callback and use myvar in your view to display the number of options

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
 @ViewChildren('ion-option')
  ionOptions: QueryList<any>;
```

and then

```
ionOptions.length;
```